# Does removing C:\Windows\System32\{java,javaw,javaws}.exe prevent Java malware?

Tags: java, windows, windows-7-x64, malware

Been using Java for a number of years, but the recent warnings about zero-day exploits concerning the JRE are troubling.

I am considering the following approaches (all on a Windows 7 Ultimate/64 bit machine):

1. Disabling Java in all browsers (long since done)
2. Uninstalling Java outright (and hence removing `C:\Windows\System32\java.exe`, `java2.exe`, and `javaws.exe`)
3. Downloading the Java JRE & JDK into another volume (`F:\Java64\jdk1.8\jre`), and having all java dependent apps (eclipse, minecraft, etc.) point directly to it.

The questions I have are:

1. Will this prevent most if not all java centric malware?
2. Can I configure the java updater to update the java JDK/JRE in `F:\Java64\jdk1.8\jre`) *without* having it reinstall into `C:\Windows\System32` behind my back?

Comment: If I have a Java program that deletes your C drive, how would executing from your F drive help with that?

Comment: @KevinWorkman, If I specifically download a java program, either by accident via sneaky malware or stupidly by not paying attention, it needs to know how to run.  If it cannot *find* the `F:\Java64` installation, then what JVM would it use?

Comment: If you specifically download a Java program, it won't run unless you tell it to. And anything that could run that Java program automatically could just delete your C drive without requiring Java anyway. The problem with Java was that the browser plugin ran without you specifically telling it to. Even the browser plugin doesn't work like that anymore, but the damage has been done and people are paranoid about Java now.

Comment: try asking in http://security.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Kevin, the only programs I'm running on purpose are fairly established ones: eclipse and minecraft currently, and both of these I can point directly to `F:\Java64`.  I wouldn't even have an environment variable pointing to it for a cmd script to use.

Comment: @Kevin, There's litterally no way for me to run a java program directly, unless I either configure an environment variable to find the JRE, or configure the application itself to directly invoke the one in `F:\Java64`.  If I encounter an established program that doesn't specifically grant me that functionality, I can create a cmd script that directly runs the `F:` java on it.

Comment: Again, not sure how you think that's more or less secure than any other approach. Also keep in mind that I can also just bundle a JRE with my application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The runtime (and the JDK, for that matter) does not need to be installed in order to use it.

I recommend the following:

- make a copy of the JRE, somewhere new, or perhaps one per dependent app
- uninstall it
- check your browser(s) for plugins and delete/disable them if they got left behind
- delete the `java.exe` files in `%windir%` if they get left behind
- do *not* point the PATH or any environment variables at a copy of the JRE

While removing or disabling the browser plugin may be sufficient, I personally wouldn't trust that it will *remain* removed or disabled.  The Java automatic updater, for example, might inadvertently reinstall them.

Of course, doing this means that you don't get automatic updates.  But Java security issues that affect legitimate programs are rare.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I've done, so thanks.  Question: While I doubt this, can the java updater update an installation in place *without* actually putting everything back in `C:\windows\system32`?  I'll have to experiment some with this, but it's less important----if I can keep malware from actually finding the JRE, then that's the largest part of the battle.  I trust the browser to keep the plugin out, but I'll have to be diligent on that front as well.

Comment: If the Java Updater service is installed, all bets are off; if it knows where your Java instance is, it might "fix" the registry settings necessary for a browser to find it, put the "missing" files back in system32, and/or relocate Java to the usual place in 
Program Files.  But AFAIK the Java Updater doesn't run unless it is installed.

Comment: Harry, yeah, that's what I figured.

Answer (score 2):

Desktop Java was never really a vector for malware, the browser plugin was. So disabling it in browsers should suffice. Moving it to another volume or deleting the files from `%Windir%` will not change anything. Uninstalling does pretty much the same as disabling the browser plugin.

Comment: No, according to [this](http://ww2.kqed.org/news/2013/01/11/experts-warn-users-to-disable-widely-used-java-software), the DHS is still recommending that java be uninstalled.  And this is not merely because of browser exploits directly running a java applet; downloaded malware could permanently infect the java JRE, which would affect *all* usages of it, even from my eclipse & minecraft invocations.

Comment: @tgm1024, the article you pointed to is more than two years old and seems directed at non-technical users.  Furthermore, the article says DHS recommends "disabling" Java, which only makes sense if it is understood to mean "... in your browser".  Anyway, if a malicious website can cause `%Windir%\java.exe` to run on your computer then you've already lost, any security flaws in that program notwithstanding.

Comment: @tgm1024 Additionally, taking computer security advice from anyone in the US government is like taking medical advice from Andrew Wakefield.